# Python when catching exceptions, how I can get the line number?

Tags: python, yaml

I know there is another thread on this but it didn't solve my problem, please read my question!

Basically, I'm parsing a YAML file to ensure it has all the correct keys and values I want. If the YAML file has an incorrect value or key that it needs to have, then I want to print a message that says where the incorrect value or key is.

Example:
Let's say for this YAML file:

> Groceries:
>   Apples: Granny
>   Milk: Skim
>   Bread: Wheat

Let's say I was expecting 'Whole' as the value for 'Milk'. If that line is line 3, how do I print a message that says "error: invalid value blah blah on LINE 3"??

Thanks so much!

Comment: read the file line by line and print the counter for your current line number when you get an error?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm fairly new to Python and programming in general. Can you give me an example? are you saying create said counter or one already exists?

Comment: don't know how u parse your file. but if you just uses some external library and get an exception you can use traceback.tb_lineno. http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html

Comment: Depends heavily on how you parse the file. I fear that most ready-made parsing libraries won't pass line numbers on - so if you can only detect the error after that libary finished parsing and returned a complete Python object, you're propably out of luck.

Comment: How do you parse the YAML? Do you use a library like PyYAML? Or do you use a different aproach?

Comment: I parse the file by using PyYAML, I import yaml then do yaml.load(sys.argv[1]) on the file, which converts it into a dictionary for python. I then use known keys in the dictionary to check for correct values, if a value is incorrect, I want to say the line number where the incorrect value exists...I feel like delnan answered my question, if it's already a python object I don't see how I'd get the line number

Comment: Well a trick that might work depending on your data is to preparse the yml document either by adding the line number as a dict value or as part of a variable name.

Answer (score 5):

From the PyYaml documentation

```
>>> try:
...     yaml.load("unbalanced blackets: ][")
... except yaml.YAMLError, exc:
...     if hasattr(exc, 'problem_mark'):
...         mark = exc.problem_mark
...         print "Error position: (%s:%s)" % (mark.line+1, mark.column+1)

Error position: (1:22)
```

Comment: I know it's a bit old but but i think `mark.line+1` needs to be just `mark.line`.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question - the asker is concerned about data validation, not syntax validation. The example is valid YAML, so loading it won't throw a YAMLError.

Comment: Without the +1 the line and column numbers seem to start at 0.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement to the question. I couldn't find a python solution but found kwalify - http://www.kuwata-lab.com/kwalify. You can use it as a command line tool. It allows you to specify the keys, and allowable values as a schema. You then validate your YAML file as follows:

kwalify -f schema.yaml document.yaml